# Pass object from Smarty to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty, smarty2

I have a smarty template that uses jQuery clones; i.e. a click on a button will call jQuery and jQuery will add a select field to a page.  However, the select field is supposed to be dynamically populated within the smarty template.

I have outlined below what i'm trying to achieve.

**addProject.php**

```
// Load supervisor list into an object and pass it to smarty
$smarty->assign_by_ref('supervisor', $supervisor->results());
$smarty->display('superusers/addProject.tpl');
```

**superusers/addProject.tpl**

```
<div>
<p class="add add-data add-another-supervisor2"><i class="sprite plus2"></i> <span>Add <b class="hide">another</b> supervsior</span></p>
</div>
<script src="js/cloneformcontrols.js"></script>
```

**js/cloneformcontrols.js**

```
$("#main").on("click", ".add-data", function() {
    var mytarget = $(this).closest('.clonable').find('.clone:last');
    var myparent = $(this).closest('.clonable');
    var filename = "../smarty/templates/default/superusers/clones/add-supervisor.tpl";
    var theCloneHtml = '<div class="clone" id="cloneID' + formNameIncrement + '">';

    var theCloneId = 'cloneID' + formNameIncrement;
    if ($(this).hasClass('add-another-supervisor2')) {filename = "../smarty/templates/default/superusers/clones/add-another-supervisor.tpl";}

    myparent.addClass('data-added');
    mytarget.after($(theCloneHtml).load(filename, function() {
        $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow');
        updateNameAttribute(theCloneId); // need to update the name atribute or validation won't work  
    }));
    formNameIncrement++;
});
```

**clones/add-another-supervisor.tpl**

```
<div class="standard-row add-admin-row input-row">
        <label class="ib ib217"> <span class="plain-select">
                <select class="inp" data-myname="supervisor[]" name="supervisor[]">
                        <option value="">Select one</option>
                        {section name="i" loop=$supervisor}
                            <option value="{$supervisor[i]->id}">{$supervisor[i]->name}</option>
                        {/section}
                </select>
                </span> </label>
        <p class="add remove-this-data fl"><i class="sprite delete2"></i> <span>&nbsp;</span></p>
</div>
```

The only part that is not working is the ***clones/add-another-supervisor.tpl*** page doesn't receive the object **$supervisor** and therefore none of the select options get filled.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Because you do not pass the `supervisor` to the `load`.  You need to store it somewhere in the `addProject.tpl` I think, in json format, in a hidden field, and inject it into the `clones/add-another-supervisor.tpl`.

Comment: Or include this `clones/add-another-supervisor.tpl` in `addProject.tpl` as a hidden, (`display: none`) and clone that.

Comment: Is there not a more elegant way of doing that?

Comment: You should not be calling the filename directly in jQuery. That is not the intentned way for smarty to work. Assignments come from PHP so it will not have the object in there. You should call a PHP file from jQuery in like an ajax call and use PHP to assign the values to the template and use smarty display to send the info back to jQuery. In the jQuery response display it on the page.